# InstallAware, Add a big SQL script problem

Tags: installation, installaware

I am trying to create an installer using InstallAware.
I have a big database that i should create during installation.
I generated the script and while trying to add the script to the MS SQL Server command, it is taking too long, about 15 min.
Is there any solution for this issue?
**Thanks for your help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up shelling out to a custom program to do SQL actions, since the MS SQL Server command didn't give me the logging and other troubleshooting visibility I needed. I would also say that installing a new database (particularly if you're installing a new SQL Server instance) takes a LONG time, and is extremely error prone. This isn't really InstallAware's fault; but due to the fact that SQL Server is a HEAVY install. If I had it to do other again, I would definitely use something like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) for any application that "normal people" (i.e. not IT pros) will be installing.

Answer (score 0):

InstallAware is known for its problems (personally I didn't manage to make it work for my installers). Are you sure it's the installer? Is the script faster when executed manually? If it is, you can try executing it through a custom action and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah it is much faster, i will try the custom action, thank you